# How to get/set current location programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to implement a feature in my app where I can see my current location and I should even have an option to set it manually, if the location is not accurate. How can this be done? Should I use a webservice or something?

**Revised**

Guess i was not very clear in my question. Sorry about it. 
I am currently able to get my lat and long. But there are times when its not very accurate. In that scenario i should be able to enter my place name (state) and i want to receive the standard lat long for that place.. i just wanted to know how to implement it ..

Comment: Please add more detail and what you have tried to your question.

Comment: When you say "option to set it manually, if the location is not accurate", is this specific to your app or to the whole phone?  In other words, if you specify the location manually to the middle of Kansas, will Google Maps (and any other location aware app) show you in the middle of Kansas?

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) is the overview of location services in Android, which you probably need.

Comment: Guess i was not very clear in my question. Sorry about it. I am currently able to get my lat and long. But there are times when its not very accurate. In that scenario i should be able to enter my place name (state) and i want to receive the standard lat long for that place.. i just wanted to know how to implement it ..

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little `MockLocationProvider` class I've written for my purposes. It just changes latitude and longitude of a location object and returns it.

```
public class MockLocationProvider {

public static Location getMockLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {
    Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    location.setLatitude(latitude);
    location.setLongitude(longitude);
    return location;
}
}
```

However, can't really understand why you'd want to use it in a real application. I'm using this just for testing. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: I know this is an oldie, but say for example I implement this code. If I open the GPS on my phone will it detect my starting point as the Lat and Long I set above? if not, can you advice what class/service I can research in order to accomplish that please.

Comment: @andre3wap here's a good start: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need Reverse Geocoding ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding ). There are some free services for this. Search for "Reverse Geocoding" and you will find some free options. I've never used them, so I can't recommend any.

Answer (score 0):

Youll need a geocoder, an api that converts a street, city name to lat. and lng. values.

- If you have already a way to make http requests and parse json you could use the google web api:
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=de , it returns good results and is kind of accurate. Furthermore it has more info than just lat and lng.
- And all in one soultion would be the google geocoder  Object that is backward compatible until api level 1: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html . This one tends to not always return good results, especially for smaller villages and not so good known places.

Ask if you need more help etc..

Julius